# Kafka jdbc connector as change data capture

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use Kafka jdbc connector to only pull in rows from my database that have changed since the last pull.

The database is controlled by another team and they have a habit of reloading the entire database twice a day even if no information have changed. They also update the field :load-time, so the kafka connector, it will always look like a change.

Is there a way to tell kafka jdbc connector to only look in the relevant columns to detect a change?

Comment: What mode are you currently using on the Connector? To clarify, JDBC polling is not the same as CDC like Debezium would give you

Comment: I was hoping that the ‘query’ mode will explicitly allow me to state which coulmns to monitor fir changes. Instead i get :timestamp+ incrementing. That doesn’t help.

Comment: Using a custom query does allow you to select certain fields, yes, but shouldn't be used for the timestamp/ID column